# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estar en el constructor y en el prototipo?

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, prototipos

¿Cuál realmente es la diferencia de una propiedad entre estar en el `prototype` o en el `constructor`? ¿Cambia algo realmente?

En este ejemplo se puede ver que el resultado final es el mismo:

```js
function A() {
  this.nombre = "Stack-A";
}

A.prototype = {
  numero: "14-A"
};

var an = new A();

console.log(an.nombre);
console.log(an.numero);

/* ============================= */

function B() {
  this.nombre = "Stack-B";
  this.numero = "14-B";
}

var bn = new B();

console.log(bn.nombre);
console.log(bn.numero);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, pues la diferencia entre inicializar un objeto y luego asignarle las propiedades en lugar de usarlas en el constructor es mayormente por cuestión de legibilidad, ahorrar código, y estar mejor estructurado.

Si bien es cierto que puede ser un poco más lioso de depurar.

Hay un poco de mejor rendimiento si lo usas en el constructor, pero es mínimo.

Por último señalaría que puedes tener varios constructores sobrecargados y eso optimizaría bastante leer el código como he dicho anteriormente, incluso puedes crear un objeto con un constructor sin parámetros y tener otro con parámetros por si deseas utilizar el objeto sin tener que iniciar ninguna propiedad.

EDIT: Tras releer tu pregunta, me gustaría añadir que cuando agregas una propiedad o una función a un prototipo se lo estás agregando una especie de "Clase" (ya que en javascript no existe la herencia). Mientras que si lo agregas en el constructor sólo estará para las instancias que hagas de la clase. Qué quiero decir con esto? Pues que si lo agregas al prototipo no podrás modificar luego esos atributos desde el objeto, mientras que los que son del constructor sí.

Ejemplo:

```
    function A() {
  this.nombre = "Stack-A";
}

A.prototype = {

  numero: "14-A"

};

var an = new A();

an.nombre = "he sido modificado";
//an.numero = "no se podría modificar a no ser que se hiciesen getters y //setters";
console.log(an.numero); //así sí se puede usar.
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: gracias hector !

Comment: de nada, es un placer, aún así tengo te he editado la respuesta para añadir información que creo que te será útil. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión sí que hay diferencia. Cuando haces esto:

```
function A() {
  this.nombre = "Stack-A";
}

A.prototype = {
  numero: "14-A"
};

var an = new A();
```

Estás definiendo una función que será el constructor de algo considerado parecido a una nueva clase. Dentro del constructor defines, usando `this`, un atributo dentro de cada objeto creado a partir de dicha función constructor (el atributo no estará dentro del objeto constructor, el cual es una función y como tal es un objeto también). Por lo tanto, cada nuevo objeto creado tendrá su propio atributo independiente al resto.

Si accedes al prototipo de la función A y allí guardas un atributo, estarás creando el atributo solo dentro del objeto prototipo de la función, y no en cada uno de los objetos instanciados a partir del constructor A. Como para cada objeto creado a partir de A se asigna como **proto** el prototipo de dicho constructor A, todo objeto instanciado podrá acceder a los atributos que contenga el objeto prototipo de la función A. Pero, si en cualquiera de dichos objetos instanciados intentas asignar un valor al atributo que está en el prototipo de A, en realidad no cambias el valor de ese atributo en el prototipo, sino que creas un nuevo atributo dentro del objeto instanciado.

A partir del objeto instanciado sólo accede automáticamente al atributo del prototipo del constructor A para leer su contenido en el caso que dicho atributo no esté en el objeto instanciado de A. Si el atributo ya está en el objeto instanciado, accede siempre al atributo de dicho objeto.

Tienes que tener claro que la función A (constructor), el prototipo de A y el objeto instanciado a partir del constructor A son tres objetos distintos, cada uno con sus atributos, pero con la característica de que los objetos instanciados a partir de A tienen acceso a los métodos y atributos del prototipo del constructor A.

En este enlace hay mucha información sobre el tema: http://www.objectplayground.com/

Comment: Buena respuesta pero te recomendaría cambiar la palabra *clase* al ser inexistente en ECMAScript.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Sí, tienes razón. Lo usé para ayudar a que se entendiese mejor. Si confunde demasiado lo elimino. Gracias :)

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Ya lo he modificado un poco mejor. :)

Comment: Luego edité la respuesta, para mostrar que sí había diferencias, como comentas, aunque quise mantener lo que puse originalmente, crees más conveniente que borre la primera parte? ya que quizás eso sería más para un lenguaje basado en clases.

Comment: @HéctorJ.OrihuelaRuiz No te preocupes. Mientras quede claro que la primera parte se refería a definir un atributo (de cada objeto instanciado), dentro o fuera de la función constructor, sin tener nada que ver con el prototipo del constructor, está bien.